# Express.static not rendering root div within create react app, giving me a blank page

Tags: reactjs, express

I am currently making a create react app with express router and node.js. Before I complete my routes within the server I wanted to make sure I could access the static files through express.static method (front end application running on port 3000 works, it is my server on port 3001 that is not serving files). I have scoured the internet for the difference between create react app and a stand alone because a stand alone imports the components within the index.html file while the create react app does not and I believe express.static can pick that up while not being able to work with create react app. Any advice would help as I am a newer developer and I cannot seem to figure out why my components aren't being rendered. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So after days and days of trying different things, i have found a slight reach around. The problem is that the files within a development create-react-app are not static until deployed. So, one solution would be to either make all functionality within a standalone app and transfer your code over or to deploy your app and server the static files, deleting every wrong instance and re deploying your revised code. I think the ladder would have less code changes as you are in the correct environment?